# How can I handle a migrated question? 

Tags: support, migration

I asked a question on Stack Overflow and the question was migrated to Super User by someone, but then the question didn't belong to me any more.  I can't edit or pick an answer for the question, what should I do?

The question is now located [here](https://superuser.com/questions/230165/why-is-a-network-id-not-needed-to-connect-to-an-ip-address)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an account on superuser.com and associate it with the Stack Overflow one. The question will automatically belong to you (I think).

Comment: To help the process along, make sure you use the same OpenID for both accounts. Also wait 24 hours - the process isn't instantaneous when you create the account on the target site after the migration.

Comment: thanks, now the problem sovled, and ChrisF is right,this takes time